# Preventing malware on one distro from infecting other distros on a dual/multi-boot system?

Tags: partition, dual-boot, malware

I'm in the process of setting-up a computer with multi-boot - 3-5 different Linux distros, maybe FreeBSD or OpenIndiana, and probably Windows. I will be partitioning a couple of SSDs, use one partition as swap for all Linux-systems, use one Linux-distro for (among other things) installing and maintaining the GRUB-bootloader on a separate boot-partition, and else each OS/distro will have it's own partition (root and everything else).

Anyway, one of the Linux-distros will basically be used for running one single program, that pulls in and runs various scripts.  While I trust the program and the scripts, it is a rather obvious way of introducing malware of many kinds.  So I would like to block this distro from accessing any of the other partitions and disks except it's own root-partition and the common swap-partition (it won't be the distro used for GRUB).

In 'ye old days before /dev became virtual, I'll probably would've tried to simply delete all the device-files for the other disks and partitions (including the one for the whole disk the partition was on) - don't know if it would've made any difference back then, don't know if it's possible with the virtual /dev of today.

It's not possible to run it virtually (must be on bare metal).  I would prefer not to dedicate an entire disk for it (eg. with it's own boot-loader that was chain-loaded from the other one), although if that is the only viable way...

So, any suggestions for ways to prevent malware running on one distro from one partition, from also installing/destroying stuff on other partitions and disks?

Comment: I'd certainly start by sanboxing that *"single program"*